# How mark memberOf for chainable method in JSDoc?

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

I have JSDoc defined method.

```js
/**
 * @memberOf cy
 * @method slotContent
 */
```

If I use this method directly, then WebStorm detect documentation correctly.

```js
cy.slotContent()
```

But, if I call this method in chainable, then WebStorm is not detect JSDoc...

```js
cy
  .get()
  .find()
  .slotContent()
```

[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: How is the `slotContent` declared?

Answer (score 0):

Watch how they do it in JSdoc website, https://jsdoc.app/tags-memberof.html